# Best way to load customer parameters in a multi-tenant angularJS application

Tags: angularjs, multi-tenant

We have a multi-tenant Angular JS single page application.  The routing for the application uses a customer identifier as part of the URL - `#/home/<KEY>` or `#/search/<KEY>/<search term>` for instance. In theory the first page served could be of any type. Each page calls an API using the customer key and other values picked up from the URL to get data for the page. So far so good.

We have some parameters - a logo, copyright statement, default language (for internationalization) - that can be loaded using a separate API call that also uses the customer KEY. These parameters need to be available as strings in partials, to drive the internationalization and perhaps in controllers.

The question is where to call the API to get these parameters and how to set them / make them available for the rest of the app. I have looked at a bunch of questions in this general area but can't find a concrete suggestion. Should we use a config in app.js? Call another script from index.html?

Appreciate people's advice.

Answer (score 0):

The right place would be to make an API call immediately after authentication to get the various Customer specific configuration data like the Customer settings for logo, language and then put them in the session storage of the browser.

I have done an implementation using Microsoft ADAL js as per the documentation given here. https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/blob/dev/README.md.

You can do this Api call in the login success event handler or similar ones in angular.

Example:
  `$scope.$on("adal:loginSuccess", function () {
        $scope.testMessage = "loginSuccess";
    });`

HTH